# How to convert an int for loop to a String or char for loop to output a series of sequences to the mouse cursor?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get Java to output every sequence of letters between "a" and "zzzzzz" to the point of the mouse cursor. I've gotten this to work successfully with int, but Java doesn't convert easily to String or char.

```java
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class robot {
    static int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread.sleep(500);
        for (int i=0; i< 30; i+=1) {
            String str = " " + i + " ";
            Robot r = new Robot();
            Thread.sleep(200);
            String text = str;
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
            Thread.sleep(200);
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to easily convert

```
for (int i=0; i< 30; i+=1) {
    String str = " " + i + " ";
```

to work with String sequences instead? I've tried for a while and nothing has worked. Even == doesn't allow it to compile.

Comment: That code complies, but it just outputs the number 0 before terminating. It doesn't even run the rest of the script. Also, it's not possible to convert from char to String, and charSelection isn't a valid type like StringSelection is.

Comment: There are 373,071,582 different sequences starting with `a` and ending with `zzzzzz`.  Assuming one second for each sequence, it will take almost 12 years to go through the sequences.

Comment: And? That's beside the point. I didn't ask for a solution to what I am doing with it, I asked how to make it execute what I need it to.

Comment: Let 0 equal space, 1 equals `a`, through 26 equals 'z'.  Set up a `for` loop from 0 through 373,071,581.  Convert the int index to letters using the transformation I outlined.

Comment: If you want to do it purely in strings, your basic problem, I would guess, is that while incrementing 'a'...'z' is easy, there's no primitive way to increment 'z' to 'aa'.  So your first step should be to write that routine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. I don't see where the code related to `Robot` is relevant to what was asked. Can you, please, edit the question, and show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code that focuses only on the specific problem?

Comment: The code does. The robot code is necessary because otherwise, people start suggesting things that cannot be used with KeyEvent and/or Clipboard types.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to implement the part with SPACE = 0, a = 1. etc. I can make the for loop easily enough, but not the converting the int index.

Comment: From some initial pattern, you're able to make a loop for `a` through `z` to add onto the end of that pattern. The next step is making a loop surrounding that, which takes the output from the previous iteration and feeds it into the nested loop again. Basically, starting from `""`, then `["a", "b", ..., "z"]`, then `["aa", "ba", ..., "za", "ab", "bb", ..., "zb", ..., "zz"]` and so forth. If you want the partial configurations (ones with less than 6 characters) to be valid, then simply preserve those intermediate results. As mentioned previously, you're going to get an exponential # of results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *'... I'm trying to get Java to output every sequence of letters between "a" and "zzzzzz" ...'*

Use a *for-loop* to iterate from `a` to `z`.
Here is an example for `a` through `zzz`, which generates *18,278* values.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++) {
    list.add(String.valueOf(c1));
    for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++) {
        list.add("%s%s".formatted(c1, c2));
        for (char c3 = 'a'; c3 <= 'z'; c3++)
            list.add("%s%s%s".formatted(c1, c2, c3));
    }
}
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

> *"... I've gotten this to work successfully with int, but Java doesn't convert easily to String or char. ..."*

Conversion is simple, here is how to convert an *int* to a *char*.

```java
int a = 97;
char c = (char) a;
```

And, how to convert an *int* to a *char*, and then to a *String*.

```java
int b = 98;
String s = String.valueOf((char) b);
```

> *"... Is it possible to easily convert ..."*

After generating the list you can just iterate each item.

```java
public static void main2(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread.sleep(500);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(c1));
        for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++) {
            list.add("%s%s".formatted(c1, c2));
            for (char c3 = 'a'; c3 <= 'z'; c3++)
                list.add("%s%s%s".formatted(c1, c2, c3));
        }
    }
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
    for (String str : list) {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        String text = str;
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    }
}
```

> *"... Is there a way to shift the window of values? For example, if I wanted to skip the single letters and go straight to triple letters ..."*

Yes, as *@OldDogProgrammer* mentioned, you could remove the first two *list.add* calls.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++)
    for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++)
        for (char c3 = 'a'; c3 <= 'z'; c3++)
            list.add("%s%s%s".formatted(c1, c2, c3));
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

> *"... or if I wanted to focus it in on a smaller part of the list?"*

You can use the *[List#subList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int))* method to capture just a portion of the list.

```java
list = list.subList(list.indexOf("zz") + 1, list.size());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well. Is there a way to shift the window of values? For example, if I wanted to skip the single letters and go straight to triple letters, or if I wanted to focus it in on a smaller part of the list?

Comment: @JacobChristonsen if you want to skip the single and double letters, can you remove `list.add(String.valueOf(c1));` and `list.add("%s%s".formatted(c1, c2));` lines ?

Comment: @JacobChristonsen, no problem.  Yes, you can remove the first and second _list.add_ calls from the _loops_.  Or, you can use the _[List#subList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int))_ method.  I've update my answer; towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that handles an arbitrary number of characters:

```java
public class StringLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxChars = 6;
        String[][] combinations = new String[maxChars][];

        combinations[0] = new String[26];
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            combinations[0][c - 'a'] = String.valueOf(c);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < maxChars; i++) {
            combinations[i] = new String[(int) Math.pow(26, i + 1)];
            String[] prevCombinations = combinations[i - 1];
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < prevCombinations.length; j++) {
                    int index = ((c - 'a') * prevCombinations.length) + j;
                    combinations[i][index] = c + prevCombinations[j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (String[] combination : combinations) {
            for (String s : combination) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As others have mentioned, this has exponential complexity, so requires a large amount of heap space and a considerable amount of time to complete. I am able to get it to run with `-Xmx16g` (a 16 gigabyte heap). 15 GB was not enough.

Comment: You could reduce the memory bloat quite a bit by making this streamable. In the simplest sense that'd mean just printing them directly, but it also applies to providing a `Spliterator` as a general solution.

Comment: It relies on memoizing the intermediate 1 to 5 digit results. Of course, you don’t have to store the 6 digit results. It could be alternatively written to recompute everything each time, but that would trade space for time.

Answer (score 0):

I created my version that just prints the character sequences from `a` to `zzzzzz` on the output console.

I use an `int` array to hold the digits which translate into characters.  You can start the character sequence anywhere you want by initializing the `int` array to the value representing the character string you're looking to start with.

Ending on a different sequence than `zzzzzz` is difficult because I test for overflow on the leftmost digit.

Here are the last few lines of my last test.

```
zzzzzt
zzzzzu
zzzzzv
zzzzzw
zzzzzx
zzzzzy
zzzzzz

Printed 321,272,406 strings in 7 minutes, 25 seconds
```

That's a lot of password cracking attempts.  As I said in my comment, one attempt per second would take almost 12 years.  Limiting the character strings to just the six-letter combinations doesn't reduce the count by a significant amount.

Here's the code I ran.

```
public class CharacterSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharacterSequence cs = new CharacterSequence();
        cs.createAllSequences();
    }
    
    private String alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    public void createAllSequences() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int length = 6;
        int[] digit = new int[length];
        boolean isRunning = true;
        int counter = 0;
        
        while (isRunning) {
            for (int index = length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
                digit[index]++;
                if (digit[index] >= alphabet.length()) {
                    digit[index] = 1;
                    if (index <= 0) {
                        isRunning = false;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (isRunning) {
                System.out.println(toSequence(digit));
                counter++;
            }
        }
        
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        elapsedTime = (elapsedTime + 500L) / 1000L;
        int minutes = (int) (elapsedTime / 60L);
        int seconds = (int) (elapsedTime % 60L);
        String s = "Printed " + String.format("%,d", counter);
        s += " strings in " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds;
        s += " seconds";
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    private String toSequence(int[] digit) {
        String s = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < digit.length; index++) {
            s += alphabet.charAt(digit[index]);
        }
        
        return s.trim();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have _elapsedTime + 500L_, why the _+ 500_?

Comment: @Reilas: To round the time to the nearest second.